# refactor rails controller that has many query parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controllers

I have a rails controller show action which shows either the parents teams of a team, the child teams of a team, or the full family tree. Currently I am doing this as a simple case statement. Is this the correct "rails" way to do it or should I refactor? If yes, any suggestions on how would be appreciated.

```
if @team= fetch_team
  case params[:tree]
  when 'parents'
    @output = @team.ancestor_ids
  when 'children'
    @output = @team.child_ids
  when 'full'
    @output = @team.full_tree
  when nil
    @output = fetch_team
  else
    @output = {message: "requested query parameter: '#{params[:tree]}' not defined"}
  end

  render json: @output
else
  render json: {message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' not found"}, status: 404
end

##

def fetch_team
 Team.find_by(name: params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would move the case into its own method on your Team model.

```
class Team
  def tree(type)
     ...
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you could just have the following

```
if @team = fetch_team
  @output = @team.tree(params[:tree])
  render json: @output
else
  render json: {message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' not found"}, status: 404
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
if @team = fetch_team
  @output = case params[:tree]
            when 'parents' then @team.ancestor_ids
            when 'children' then @team.child_ids
            when 'full' then @team.full_tree
            when nil then @team
            else {message: "requested query parameter: '#{params[:tree]}' not defined"}
            end

  render json: @output
else
  render json: {message: "team: '#{params[:id]}' not found"}, status: 404
end
```

Comment: A second ago I saw `@team == fetch_team`

Comment: It seems like you are calling fetch_team twice in this example, if the params[:tree] is nil?  `when nil then fetch_team` => Shouldn't this just be `when nil then @team` (which is already set earlier). I realize that this was in the original example, but it's a further edit.

Comment: @KurtFunai Overlooked... Thanks